# How to access composed children?

Tags: aurelia

I have a list of composed elements:

```html
<compose repeat.for="foo of someList" view-model="./bar" model.bind="foo">
```

Now, from the parent, I would like to call a function on a specific `bar` view model. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `view-model.ref` in your compose tag:

```html
<compose repeat.for="foo of someList" view-model="./bar" model.bind="foo" view-model.ref="foo.barviewmodel">
```

You can replace `view-model.ref` by `compose.ref`. The both give the same result.

And in the parent you can call a function on a `bar` view model like this:

```js
this.someList[2].barviewmodel.currentViewModel.action();
```

It works, but I don't know if it's a public api. See [this issue](https://github.com/aurelia/templating-resources/issues/90) for more details